# how to use default lxde theme instead of lubuntu-theme?

Tags: lubuntu, themes, lxde

I have install Lubuntu 12.10. I really didn't like the lubuntu-theme. 
Its very confusing to distinguish whats there on task bar. 
Therefore, I wanted the theme like fedora lxde or default-lxde theme.

Please provide me the step to install/use default-lxde theme, as it is dark and edgy.

Answer (score -3):

You should Install the Vanilla lxde:

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```